# Find number of co-occurring elements between dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame that has a website, categories, and keywords for that website.

```
Url  | categories                                | keywords
Espn | [sport, nba, nfl]                         | [half, touchdown, referee,  player, goal]
Tmz  | [entertainment, sport]                    | [gossip, celebrity, player]
Goal [ [sport, premier_league, champions_league] | [football, goal, stadium, player, referee]
```

Which can be created using this code:

```
data = [{ 'Url': 'ESPN', 'categories': ['sport', 'nba', 'nfl'] ,
         'keywords': ["half", "touchdown", "referee",  "player", "goal"] },
         { 'Url': 'TMZ', 'categories': ["entertainment", "sport"] ,
           'keywords': ["gossip", "celebrity", "player"] },
         { 'Url': 'Goal', 'categories': ["sport", "premier_league", "champions_league"] ,
           'keywords': ["football", "goal", "stadium", "player", "referee"]},
       ]

df =pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For all the word in the keywords column, I want to get the frequency of categories associated with it. The results might look like this:

> {half: {sport:  1, nba: 1, nfl: 1},  touchdown : {sport:  1, nba: 1,
> nfl: 1},  referee: {sport:  2, nba: 1, nfl: 1, premier_league: 1,
> champions_league:1 },  player: {sport:  3, nba: 1, nfl: 1,
> premier_league: 1, champions_league:1 },  gossip: {sport:1,
> entertainment:1},  celebrity: {sport:1, entertainment:1},  goal:
> {sport:2, premier_league:1, champions_league:1,  nba: 1, nfl: 1},
> stadium:{sport:1, premier_league:1, champions_league:1} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns contain lists, you can explode them to repeat a row once for each element per list:

```py
result = (
    df.explode("keywords")
    .explode("categories")
    .groupby(["keywords", "categories"])
    .size()
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I keep getting this error: `MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False`

Comment: Also, `categories, keywords` are empty. They contain nothing after I ran this code: `df[col].str.extractall(pattern).droplevel(1).rename(columns={0: col})
    for col in ["categories", "keywords"]`

Comment: Can you export the first few rows of your DataFrame to JSON? `df.iloc[:5].to_json(None)` There are some data type mismatch between what you have and  I have and I think you have